# Reordering table columns with react via drag and drop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-dnd

I have an html table that should be able to reorder rows as well as columns.

[image]

Reordering rows is pretty [straight forward](https://gaearon.github.io/react-dnd/examples-sortable-simple.html) but reordering columns is pretty hard since the cells of a column do not share the same parent element.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Col 1</td>
    <td>Col 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Col 1</td>
    <td>Col 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How do I implement column-dragging with react?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? Im stuck with the exact same issue.

Comment: This might work. https://github.com/schrodinger/fixed-data-table-2

Comment: No not yet. I went with a simpler approach.

Answer (score 1):

You should add additional layer of abstraction between data and view - where column indexes will be used. For example:

```
var data : [["a","b","c"],["a2","b2","c2"]];
var columns = [2,1,0];

function getData(row, col) {
   return data[row][columns[col]];
}
```

Then when you drag columns - you just change indexes inside columns var.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But my problem is, that I am not able to drag multiple elements at the same time, since they do not share a common root node. Your answer targets performance issues. My question is more DOM/React oriented.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll have to implement a custom DragLayer in order to get this to do what you want it to do - that way, you'll have full control over what the drag preview looks like, and can make it render out a column instead of just the single cell you would get from the basic preview.

Then you can just make it so that if a column is being dragged all of its cells get display: none or something so that they disappear, and your custom DragLayer then shows the user the column rendered in a new table as your preview.

He has a pretty good tutorial on how to write a custom DragLayer here: http://gaearon.github.io/react-dnd/examples-drag-around-custom-drag-layer.html which you can follow along for help.